# compactness in topology of pointwise convergence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness

I started reading about the topology of pointwise convergence. So far I do not feel quite comfortable with this theory. Maybe one can help me out in a more concrete example case.

Let's consider sequences, so $a : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R},x \mapsto a(x)$.

In the topology of pointwise convergence it holds now that

$$(a)_n \to (A) \iff (a(x))_n \to A(x),\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \quad (1)$$

I hope so far I somehow boiled it down correctly to that concrete case.

Now I wonder what it means for a set $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ of sequences to be compact in the topology of pointwise convergence.

First, I need to get a feeling about "open sets" in that topology and how (1) defines those open sets -- I do not quite get the link.

After that I would need to show, that every open cover of $\mathcal{S}$ has a finite subcover, right? What would that mean precisely, I mean in doing..

ADDED STUFF

Consider we want to show, that $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is compact in the topology of pointwise convergence.

By, $S_n$ we denote the projections. Assume we know, that all $S_n$ are bounded.

Further assume, that for every sequence in $\mathcal{S}$ we know, that the resulting projected sequences have a convergent subsequence of which the limit lies in the corresponding $S_n$. Does this suffice to show that $\mathcal{S}$ is compact?

Comment: Use that the topology of pointwise convergence is the product topology $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. In that topology, a set is open exactly *iff* if it's a product of open subsets $(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ *and* only for only finitely many of these $U_i \neq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @topoload: Such subsets are indeed compact, but there are many more compact subsets which are not of this form. Think of compact subsets of $R^2$: Are all of them products of compacts in $R$?

Comment: @topoload Btw, I my first comment I made a mistake - the *cylinder sets*, i.e. the products of open subsets $(U_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ where only for finitely many $i$ you have $U_i \neq \mathbb{R}$, aren't *all* the open sets of the product topology. In general, each open set is a *union* of such cylinder sets, not directly *equal* to a cylinder set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $M \subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ endowed with the topology of pointwise convergence, i.e. the product topology, let $$
  M_n = \{x_n \,: \, (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\}
$$
be the projections of $M$ onto the factors of the product space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. Then you have that

1. If $M$ is compact, all the projections $M_n$ are compact. Thus, all the $M_n$ being compact is a necessary condition for $M$ being compact.
2. It is possible that all $M_n$ are compact but $M$ isn't. Thus, all the $M_n$ being compact is not, in general, a sufficient condition for $M$ being compact.
3. However, if $M = \prod_{i=1}^\infty M_n$, i.e. if $M$ is the *product* of all it's projections, rather than just a subset of that product, and if all the $M_n$ are compact, then $M$ is compact. Thus, for *products* all the $M_n$ being compact *is* a sufficient condition for $M$ being compact.

---

**Proof of (1):**

The product topology on $X^Y$ is the coarsest topology such that all the projections ($y \in Y$) $$
  p_y \,:\, X^Y \to X \,:\, (x_i)_{i \in Y} \to x_y
$$
are continuous. In the language of sequences of real numbers, that means that the topology of pointwise convergence is the coarsest topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such that all the mappings $$
  p_n \,:, \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} \,:\, (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \to x_n \text{,}
$$
i.e. the mappings which map a sequence to it's $n$-th value, are continuous.

Thus, since the image of compact sets is compact under continuous mappings, if $M \subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is compact in the topology of pointwise convergence, then all the sets $$
  M_n := p_n(M) = \{x_n \,:\, (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \in M\}
$$
are compact in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, for every compact set of sequences (in the topology of pointwise convergence) the set of $n$-th values is compact (in $\mathbb{R}$).

That leaves the question of whether the $M_n$ being all compact (in $\mathbb{R}$) is a sufficient condition open, though - it only proves the compactness of the $M_n$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) to be *necessary* for the compactness of $M$ (in the topology of pointwise convergence).

**Proof of (2):**

Let $$
  M = \{s^k \,|\, k \in \mathbb{N}\} \text{ where } s^k = (\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{k-1\textrm{ times}},k,0,\ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \text{,}
$$
i.e. $M$ is the set of sequences $s^k$ with $s^k_n = k\delta_{n,k}$ ($\delta$ is the Kronecker delta here). Then $M_n = \{0,k\}$ which are all clearly compact. Now let $$
  O_n = p^{-1}_n\left((n-\tfrac{1}{2},n+\tfrac{1}{2})\right) = \left\{ (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \,\big|\, x_n \in (n-\tfrac{1}{2},n+\tfrac{1}{2})\right\}
$$
and observe that $s^k \in O_n$ exactly if $n = k$, since only then is $s^k_n = k\delta_{n,k} \in (n-\tfrac{1}{2},n+\tfrac{1}{2})$. Also note that the $O_n$ are, as preimages under a continuous function of an open set, open. Thus, $$
  \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty O_i \supset M \text{,}
$$
is an covering of $M$ with open sets. But since $s^k \in O_n$ only if $k=n$, no finite number of sets $O_n$ suffices to cover $M$. We've thus found a covering of $M$ with open sets without a finite subcover, and $M$ is therefore not compact, even though all the projections $M_n$ are compact (even finite).

---

There are two intuitive reasons for (2)

1. The projections lose quite a lot of information about $M$. Start with a sequence of compact $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, and set $M = \prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} M_n$. Now, this $M$ will (I think) be compact (basically by tychonov's theorem). But there are a lot of subsets $\hat M \subset M$ which have the *same* projections $M_n$. If the condition were sufficient, *all* of these would have to be compact.
2. To show that the condition is sufficient, one would need to somehow *find* a finit subcover for every cover $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ of an $M$ whose projections $M_n$ are compact. But the only starting point would be the projections of the open sets $O_i$. Now, one can of course, for each $n$ seperately, find a finite subcover of $M_n$ within the $(p_n(O_i))_{i\in I}$. But that leaves you with countably many finite subcovers, which doesn't really help with finding *one* finite subcover with the product space.

Comment: @topoload Well, in $\mathbb{R}$ compact means bounded and closed...

Comment: Exactly. I understood "Is there a way to obtain a necessary (sic!) condition for compactness in the topology of pointwise convergence which uses that all $M_n$ are bounded" as asking for a *version* of my necessary condition which, instead of saying $M_n$ *must* be compact, says $M_n$ *must* be bounded. My answer is yes, but you must say $M_n$ must be bounded and *closed* because that *means* compact in $\mathbb{R}$. But the condition is still only necessary, i.e. if $M$ is compact than all the $M_n$ must be bounded and closed.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I'm not sure we're looking at the space you're really interested in. Are you aware that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the space of *sequences* of real numbers, not the space of function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? In particular - *pointwise convergence* for $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ means pointwise convergence of *sequences* of *sequences* to a particular *sequence*.

Comment: @topoload I.e., say you have a sequence $(s_n)$ where each $s_n$ is itself a sequence $s_n = (a^n_i) \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ ($a^n$ is NOT a power here!). Pointwise convergence of $s_n$ to $s = (a_i)$ then means that for every $i$, the sequnce of $i$-th values of the $s_n$ converges to $a_i$, i.e. that for every $i$, $a^n_i \to a_i$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @topoload However, the *usual* use-case of pointwise convergence is for sequences of *functions* $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, i.e. you're looking at sequences $(f_n)$ where $f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, and say $f_n \to f$ if $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$. The correct space to look at for *this* situation is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. You still use the corresponding topology of pointwise convergence though (just on a larger space), so my answer stays essentially correct, since it doesn't use that $\mathbb{N}$ is countable..

Comment: @topoload Ok, I believe I managed to find a counter-example to the sufficiency of the condition, i.e. a set whose projections are all compact but which itself isn't. Took me quite a few tries to construct this correctly - I hope there aren't any mistakes left, but better check carefully if you rely on this.

Comment: @topoload Dunno, you'd have to provide more details (though probably best as another question). Note that even a global bound on the $M_n$, i.e. some fixed $[a,b]$ such that $\forall n \,:\, M_n \subset [a,b]$, won't help I think. It seems that instead of $s^k_n = k\delta_{k,n}$, it suffices to have $s^k_n = \delta_{k,n}$ and to accordingly set $O_n = p^{-1}_n((1/2,3/2))$.

Comment: @topoload I added a summary of the various necessary and sufficient conditions for $M$ being compact. Hopefully things are clear now. Your confusion stems, I think, from somehow thinking that you can *reconstruct* $M$ from it's projections. You can't. Not even in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take the unit circle, and remove a single point at $x,y \notin \{-1,1,0\}$. The projections to the $x$ and $y$-Axis will still be the interval $[-1,1]$, yet the circle with one point removed isn't compact. But of course, the unit *rectangle*, i.e. the product of the projections, *is* compact!

Comment: That's it! I mixed those up. Thank you! I updated the other question accordingly. I am cleaning up my comments here as they were due to my misunderstanding and possibly only disturbing for later readers.